# Не получается добавить System.Threading.Tasks

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужен Task, но не получается его добавить

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы напрасно ищете сборку с соответствующим названием. Класс Task вместе с пространством имён System.Threading входит в mscorlib.dll, она у вас явно подключена. Возможно, что ваш проект собирается под версию .NET ниже четвёртой. Класс Task появился именно там. Проверьте в свойствах проекта на вкладке Application в поле Target Framework. 
При этом если вам помимо Task понадобится ещё и async/await, то вам придётся сменить версию фреймворка минимум на 4.5

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно, Framework 3.5. С более свежим всё нормально работает

Answer (score 3):

Пространство имен `System.Threading.Tasks` находится в библиотеке `mscorlib` (подключена по умолчанию во все проекты) начиная с .NET 4.0. Вся полнота асинхронного программирования доступна начиная с .NET 4.5

У вас же, по всей видимости, ничего выше .NET 3.5 не стоит. Возможно, вам стоит воспользоваться Async CTP (если вы его еще найдете), пакетом [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) или стянуть реализацию необходимых классов из проекта [`Mono`](https://github.com/mono/referencesource/tree/master/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks)